# How would I store a datetime, then compare the datetime against current datetime?

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime, discord.py

Currently I'm getting the datetime of a discord message in UTC then adding it into a database under the xp_time table.

My confusion is around retrieving that datetime then comparing it against the current datetime to see if 60 seconds has passed. I've tried a few attempts with different solutions but I can't figure it out.

```
        db = sqlite3.connect('xpdata.db')
        cursor = db.cursor()

        user_id = int(msg.author.id)
        guild_id = msg.guild.id
        time_id = msg.created_at

        sqlupdate = (f'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO xpdata(user_id,guild_id, xp, level,xp_time) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)')
        val = (user_id, guild_id, xp_inc, 0, time_id)
        cursor.execute(sqlupdate, val)
        db.commit()
```

Below is kinda where I'm confused, I want to return the difference (if possible) then check if it's over a 60 second difference then continue updating the user's xp

I know it's written wrong! but that's why I have the question haha.

```
        #Check for cooldown
        select = (f"SELECT julianday('now') - julianday(xp_time) FROM xpdata")
        cursor.execute(select)

        if select > 59:

            select = (f'SELECT * FROM xpdata WHERE user_id = {user_id} AND guild_id = {guild_id}')
            cursor.execute(select)
            for row in cursor.fetchall():
                xp_grab = row[2]
                lvl_grab = row[3]
[...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using julianday 1 is equal to 1 day, time is the decimal portion. I'd suggest using the time in seconds which can be represented using strftime('%s', time_value).

The `strftime` function is very flexible and you can use `strftime('%s','now','-59 seconds')` as the time 59 seconds ago.

So you could use :-

If you use julianday then 1 is 1 day. I'd suggest using `strftime('%s')` where 1 is 1 second.

`SELECT  strftime('%s','now','-59 second') - strftime('%s',xp_time) FROM xpdata;`

**Example**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS xpdata (xp_time TEXT);
INSERT INTO xpdata VALUES(datetime('now','-120 seconds')); /* inserts value 120 seconds ago */
SELECT  strftime('%s','now') - strftime('%s',xp_time) FROM xpdata;
```

The above results in :-

[image]

**Other considerations**

Alternately you could use :-

`SELECT strftime('%s',xp_time) < strftime('%s','now','-59 seconds') FROM xpdata;`

This would return 1 (true for more than 59 seconds) or 0 (false if 59 seconds or less).

Of course it could be that the above could perhaps be used in the select or even to just do the update without prior checks (*I want to return the difference (if possible) then check if it's over a 60 second difference then continue updating the user's xp*)

Along the lines of (update user by adding 10 xp points if xp_time is more than 59 seconds ago) :-

```
UPDATE xpdata SET xp = xp + 10 WHERE user_id = 1 AND guild_id = 1 AND strftime('%s',xp_time) < strftime('%s','now','-59 seconds');
```

You may wish to consider reading [SQLite Date and Time Functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: This is the most complex thing I've encountered yet. Thank you for explaining it !